# Service Registry in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I see that since Hibernate 4 in order to get Session Factory from configuration we need to make use of ServiceRegistry.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

What's the purpose of ServiceRegistry. Why is it required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have redesigned sessionFactory to pass the argument as Serviceregistry object. Some explanation is there in the jira ticket.

> Currently a SessionFactory is built by throwing a bunch of stuff into
>   a Configuration object, stirring it, letting it come to a boil, and
>   then pulling out the SessionFactory. In seriousness, there are a few
>   problems with the way we currently operate within a Configuration and
>   how we use it to build a SessionFactory:
>
> The general issue that there is no "lifecycle" to when various pieces
>   of information will be available. This is an important omission in a
>   number of ways:
>
> 1) consider schema generation. currently we cannot
>   even know the dialect when a lot of db object names are being
>   determined. this would be nice because it would allow us to
>   transparently handle table/column names which are also
>   keywords/reserved-words in the dialect, for example.
>
> 2) static-ness of
>   types and the type-mappings. Because we currently have nothing to
>   which to scope them. Ideally a type instance would be aware of the
>   SessionFactory to which it is bound. Instead, what we have now is to
>   change API methods quite a lot of the time to add in the
>   SessionFactory as a passed parameter whenever it is discovered that it
>   is needed.
>
> 3) also, most (all?) of the "static" configuration
>   parameters in Hibernate are currently required to be so because of
>   their use from within these static types; thus scoping types would
>   allow us to also scope those config parameters (things like
>   bytecode-provider, use of binary streams, etc).
>
> Ideally what I see happening is a scheme where users build a
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Settings (or something similiar) instance
>   themselves. Additionally they would apply metadata to a registry of
>   some sort (lets call it MetadataRegistry for now). Then in order to
>   build a SessionFactory, they would supply these two pieces of
>   information (via ctor? via builder?). The important aspect though is
>   that the information in MetadataRegistry would not be dealt with until
>   that point in time, which would allow us to guarentee that resolving
>   schema object names, types, etc would have access to the runtime
>   Settings (and specifically the dialect)

Link to the [ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2578)